# Django : How can i hide field with empty value in change view ( permission can view ) in admin

Tags: python, django

How can i hide field with empty value in change view in admin

i have groupe of permission  goup1 and group 2  and group 3

group 1 : permission = can edit + can add + can view + can delete

group 2 : permission = can edit + can dd

group 3 permission = can view

the problem is in group3 , i have empty field (file field or charfield ...)

i need to hide the empty to group3 so the group can see juste field with value and not the empty (se image example)

[i need to hide the empty field ,it's dynamic field , id'ont have the same fields always ,maybe one maybe more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUyL5.jpg)

[file field also , if no file , so they must be hiden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D6Fh.jpg)

Admin.py

```
class AnnexeCooperationBilateraleInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Annexe
    extra = 1
     #formset = RequiredInlineFormSet
    exclude =["cooperationMultilaterale",'am','calip']


class InstrumentJuridiqueDocCooperationBilateraleInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = InstrumentJuridiqueDoc
    extra = 1
    max_num = 1
     #formset = RequiredInlineFormSet
    exclude =["cooperationMultilaterale",'am','calip']


class CooperationBilateraleAdmin(ManyToManyAdmin):

    fieldsets = [
        ( '', {
            'fields': ['paysPartenaires', 'instrumentJuridique',('partenaire','gouvernement','paysP','etat','adefinir'),'objet', 'axeCooperation']
        }),
        ('Autres élements à rajouter ?', {
            'fields': ['infoPlus', ]
        }),
        ('', {
            'fields': [ 'acteJuridique',('dateSignature','dateEntreeVigueur' ),('duree','dureeplus5ans', 'renouvellement'), ('pays', 'villeSignature')]
        }),
        ('Base Documentaire', {
            'fields': [], 'description': 'Joindre le(s) fichier(s) '}),

    ]
    class Media:
        js = (
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js',  # jquery
            '/static/admin/js/assets_admin.js',  # project static folder
        )
        css = {
            'all': ('/static/admin/css/CooperationBilateraless.css',)
        }


    def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):


        user = get_user_model()
        group = request.user.groups.values_list('id', flat=True).first()

        if  request.user.has_perm('system.edit_CooperationBilaterale') or  request.user.has_perm('system.add_CooperationBilaterale'):
            context['media'] += forms.Media(
                css={"all": ("/static/admin/css/CooperationBilaterale.css",)},
                js=["/static/admin/js/CooperationBilaterale.js"],
            )

        if request.user.has_perm('system.edit_CooperationBilaterale') or request.user.has_perm('system.add_CooperationBilaterale'):
            context['adminform'].form.fields['partenaire'].queryset = PartenaireInternational.objects.filter( caneva__contains=',2,')
            context['adminform'].form.fields['etat'].queryset = Etat.objects.filter(type__exact=3)
            context['adminform'].form.fields['duree'].queryset = DureeCooperation.objects.all().order_by('order')


        if group==2: # Goupe  Bilatérale Afrique et Pays arabes
            context['adminform'].form.fields['paysPartenaires'].queryset = Pays.objects.filter(Q(region=1) | Q(region=2)).distinct()
        if group==3: # Goupe  Bilatérale Europe
            context['adminform'].form.fields['paysPartenaires'].queryset = Pays.objects.filter(region=6).distinct()
        if group == 4: # Goupe  Bilatérale Amérique et Pays d'Asie
            context['adminform'].form.fields['paysPartenaires'].queryset = Pays.objects.filter(Q(region=3) | Q(region=4)).distinct()

        return super(CooperationBilateraleAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, *args, **kwargs)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if getattr(obj, 'created_by', None) is None:
            obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.save()

    #def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        #readonly_fields = [];
        #readonly_fields.append('partenaire')
        #return readonly_fields


    #autocomplete_fields = ['paysPartenaires','instrumentJuridique','pays']
    inlines = (InstrumentJuridiqueDocCooperationBilateraleInline,AnnexeCooperationBilateraleInline,)
    pass




admin.site.register(CooperationBilaterale, CooperationBilateraleAdmin)
```

if possible i need solution that i can use it in the admin model.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution using jQuery

```
if (!$) {
    // Need this line because Django also provided jQuery and namespaced as django.jQuery
    $ = django.jQuery;
}


$(window).on('load', function() {

$('div.readonly').each(function(){
  if($(this).text()=='-' || $(this).text()==''){
   $(this).parent().css( "display", "none" );
  }


})

});
```

it's hide all field with empty value in change form ( permission can view only)